# Updating documents in Cloud Firestore based on a query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

is it possible to set values with firebase cloud function that includes a where clause?

E.g

```
admin.firebase.firestore().collection('Accounts').where("imagePathName", '==', docNamed).set({
  original: 'trial'
});
```

this is giving me an error.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with Cloud *Functions*. Did you mean Cloud *Firestore*?

Comment: yes cloud firestore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [set()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/DocumentReference#set) to create or update a document represented by a [DocumentReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/DocumentReference) type object.

A query doesn't have a set method.  You would instead have to obtain all the documents from the Query using [get()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/Query#get) to obtain a [QuerySnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/QuerySnapshot), iterate that, then call set() on each document individually.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add this to the answer of Doug Stenvenson.

Once you get your `querySnapshot` with something like: `admin.firestore().collection('Accounts').where("imagePathName", '==', docNamed).get();`)

The following code didn't update all the documents as I would (but only one):

```
querySnapshot.forEach(async doc => {
  await doc.ref.update(newData);
});
```

**What I had to do instead to make it work was:**

```
for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
  await doc.ref.update(newData);
}
```